# Return <bar>foo</bar> instead of <string>foo</string> in WCF rest method

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, formatting

I have a REST web method in .NET 3.5:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = Verbs.Get)]
public string GetBar()
{
   return "foo";
}
```

The response gets formatted as `<string>foo</string>` while I would prefer `<bar>foo</bar>` instead. Does anyone know how to do that? I feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Why not? If somebody spot a typo, and feels like rephrasing the question. No pb by me :-)

Comment: People with sufficient rep can already edit your question without making it community wiki.  The problem with community wiki is that no-one gets any rep points for answering it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, didn't know about this rule. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning XML from a WCF service you usually use one of the serializers, either the DataContractSerializer or the XmlSerializer.  I was not able to get the DataContractSerializer to return what you are looking for but here is one way that works with the XmlSerializer.

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "bar")]
 [OperationContract]
 public bar GetData() {
   return new bar(); 
 }



  [XmlRoot(Namespace = "")]
    public class bar : IXmlSerializable {

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
            writer.WriteString("foo");
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Eventually I just gave up trying to get the serializers to do what I wanted and just started returning "stream" from my contracts and doing the XML generation myself.